# Paypal for iOS in Arabic language giving issue

Tags: ios, paypal, xcode6, paypal-sandbox

I have implemented PayPal in my app. I have also made this app for two languages, English and Arabic with localization. Everything works fine and when app is running in English but when I switch to Arabic and make payments using PayPal, it always gives error.

```
  VALIDATION_ERROR - معلومات الدفع غير صحيحة. يرجى التصحيح وإعادة الإرسال. (400) | PayPal Debug-ID:MY_ID [sandbox, PayPal iOS SDK 2.4.2] | Details: (
    {
    field = "transactions[0].amount.details.subtotal";
    issue = "Currency amount must be non-negative number, may optionally contain exactly 2 decimal places separated by '.', optional thousands separator ',', limited to 7 digits before the decimal point";
}
```

Also because of localization in PayPal as well the amount displayed is like this

```
 $٤.,,.
```

What I am assuming here is that in Arabic language "0" is considered as "." and PayPal is taking this as a decimal and hence generating error. I have searched a lot but unable to find the solution. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issues described here have now been resolved in a new release of the [PayPal-iOS-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK), version 2.10.0.

Comment: Hello Dave,
Thanks for the reply.

1) When we switched to Arabic, the language we select was "Arabic" and Region was "India". Although we tried with Saudi Arabia, Kuwait and UAE also. For Locale we are passing the language in which device is running i.e either "en" or "ar".

2)  NSDecimal number that we are passing are following
     subtotal: 40,
    shipping tax: 0,
    Total: 40.

3) Currency code we are using is USD. We also tried SAR but that was unsupported and resulted in crash.

Comment: @user2732863 just to confirm, for the display `$٤.,..` is correct, right? Or in this situation would an Arabic speaker expect to instead see `$40.00`?

Comment: Yes an Arabic would expect to see $40.00 in this situation.

Comment: Thanks! But the same Arabic speaker would expect to see an amount in the currency of an Arabic-speaking country (e.g., SAR) displayed using Arabic script?

Comment: Hi Dave, very sorry for the late reply. I know you are working on it and delay from my side was not good. If you will show the amount in SAR then we have to check from our side and had to adjust amount with respect to SAR currency? So $40 will be actually 150 SAR? And that will be amount we have to show to the user?

Comment: Also, right now this is limited to English and Arabic. But if user has set any third language say Spanish in that case app will be showing english but Paypal SDK will show content in Spanish and there currency will be shown. As when we switched to spanish language it showed amount like this $40,00

Comment: It's up to your app to choose the currency and the amount; the PayPal SDK will not convert from one currency to another. So if you tell us USD $40, then it will be displayed as `$40.00` regardless of the user's language and region settings. But, theoretically, if you tell us 150 SAR (if we someday actually supported SAR), which would make more sense for users: `150 ﷼‎`, or the equivalent written in Arabic digits?

Comment: However, we're about to release an updated version of the library today, at which time I'll edit my original answer accordingly. At which point I think that there will be value in keeping this whole discussion available for future reference.